# Latex reference obtaining a section including color

Tags: color, titlesec

I have the code:

```
\definecolor{amaranth}{rgb}{0.9, 0.17, 0.31}

\titleformat{\section}
        [runin]
        {\color{amaranth}\sffamily\filright}
        {\thesection}
        {0.5em}
        {}

\section{One}
\label{sec:One}

Reference the section One \textbf{\ref{sec:One}}
```

below that produces:

[image: I result]

and I want to get the below result:

[image: I want this outcome]

`\ref` wish the command, type the color of the `\section`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Define a macro `\secref` to format the output to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor}

\definecolor{amaranth}{rgb}{0.9, 0.17, 0.31}

\titleformat{\section}
        [runin]
        {\color{amaranth}\sffamily\filright}
        {\thesection}
        {0.5em}
        {}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\textcolor{amaranth}{\bfseries\sffamily\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\label{sec:One}

Reference the section One \secref{sec:One}.

\end{document}
```